# Hibernate: could not load requested class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, h2

I am using Hibernate with mysql but on runtime I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver org.h2.Driver class not found
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at driver.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.h2.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:104)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.h2.Driver
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    ... 15 more
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/ict
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root
   </property>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using annotated classes like

```
@Entity
@Table (name="method_msisdn_info")
public class MSISDN {

    public MSISDN(){}

    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="msisdn_id")
    int msisdn_id;
    public int getMsisdn_id() {
        return msisdn_id;
    }
    public void setMsisdn_id(int msisdn_id) {
        this.msisdn_id = msisdn_id;
    }

    @Column(name="destination_msisdn")
    BigInteger destination_msisdn;
    public BigInteger getDestination_msisdn() {
        return destination_msisdn;
    }
    public void setDestination_msisdn(BigInteger destination_msisdn) {
        this.destination_msisdn = destination_msisdn;
    }

    @Column(name="product_list")
    String product_list;
    public String getProduct_list() {
        return product_list;
    }
    public void setProduct_list(String product_list) {
        this.product_list = product_list;
    }

    @Column(name="country")
    String country;
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Column(name="operator")
    String operator;
    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }
    public void setOperator(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    @Column(name="destination_currency")
    String destination_currency;
    public String getDestination_currency() {
        return destination_currency;
    }
    public void setDestination_currency(String destination_currency) {
        this.destination_currency = destination_currency;
    }

    @Column(name="error_code")
    int error_code;
    public int getError_code() {
        return error_code;
    }
    public void setError_code(int error_code) {
        this.error_code = error_code;
    }

    @Column(name="wholesale_price_list")
    String wholesale_price_list;
    public String getWholesale_price_list() {
        return wholesale_price_list;
    }
    public void setWholesale_price_list(String wholesale_price_list) {
        this.wholesale_price_list = wholesale_price_list;
    }

    @Column (name ="retails_price_list")
    String retail_price_list;
    public String getRetail_price_list() {
        return retail_price_list;
    }
    public void setRetail_price_list(String retail_price_list) {
        this.retail_price_list = retail_price_list;
    }

    @Column(name="marked_processed")
    int marked_processed;
    public int getMarked_processed() {
        return marked_processed;
    }
    public void setMarked_processed(int marked_processed) {
        this.marked_processed = marked_processed;
    }
}
```

finally I create session like

```
SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().addPackage("models").addAnnotatedClass(MSISDN.class).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
```

Comment: Tell a bit more about how you configure your persistance. It looks like the application is trying to load a H2 db driver while you seem to configure a mySql driver in your hibernate cfg. It does not look like your program is using the hibernate.cfg.xml you have posted here. Might be you have another version of that file on your class path.

Comment: I placed my hibernate.cfg.xml inside the src folder.

Comment: Is that file also in your classpath when you run your application? E.g. if you are using maven, you should better put it in the resources folder.

Comment: No, I am not using maven.
and yes, when I run, the (exact same)hibernate.cfg.xml is created in the bin directory i.e. it does go in the binary package.

Comment: But you are right, because no matter where I place my hibernate.cfg.xml, the same error occurs (meaning it does not complain that it cant find the cfg.xml). But I still dont get how to rectify the error.

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html#d0e184
Seems like the `hibernate.dialect` property should not be inside the `session-factory` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (but I'm not sure) that creating the `Configuration` object like you do requires to specify the configuration xml file.
Try like this (with me it worked):

```
Configuration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration().addPackage("models").addAnnotatedClass(MSISDN.class);
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
```

Anyway, I noticed that you are using a lot of deprecated methods. I will suggest you to use not deprecated methods.

Comment: I solved it. Though I didn't specified the cfg.xml file the way you did, but specified the properties individually. The reason of the problem was that, hibernate was picking database, dialect and other properties from the global hibernate.properties file present in the hibernate jar I had added to my classpath.

Answer (score 0):

it throws ClassNotFoundException for class org.h2.Driver .. do you have a jar containing this class? check http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.h2.Driver

Comment: It shouldnt be asking for that class because I am using mysql and not h2.